# Define buildConfigField for androidTest

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, gradle-plugin

I'm defining a particular field in the `BuildConfig` for getting the `URL` during runtime. So, for each build type, I use a different string:

```
    prod {
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"abc.com\""
    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"efg.com\""
    }
```

Is it possible to define a different URL while running the android tests? I tried putting this setting under `sourceSets->androidTest`, but it's not accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass it as a parameter to `connectedAndroidTest` task.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        prod {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${getBaseUrl("abc.com")}\""
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"${getBaseUrl("efg.com")}\""
        }
    }
}

def getBaseUrl(String fallback) {
    return project.hasProperty("base_url") ? project.getProperties().get("base_url") : fallback
}
```

Then passing parameters via `-P`:

```
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pbase_url="xxx.com"
./gradlew connectedProdAndroidTest  -Pbase_url="yyy.com"
```

Comment: Good solution, thank you. The function can be simplified to return project.getOrDefault().get("base_url", fallback)

Answer (score 0):

Add custom `BuildConfig.java` to `your.app.package` in test/androidTest dir.

Android Studio marks it red but works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs that, Use this function to check tests build

```
boolean isUnitTestBuild() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("test(\\w*)(Release|Debug)")
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

    return matcher.find()
}
```